# Multiple Exchange Servers and creating Email items with VBA for a specific account

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, exchange-server

I have Outlook 2021 on my PC. In my single Outlook profile I have six Exchange accounts defined that all point to different Exchange Servers for clients.

In the left pane of Outlook I have multiple accounts, multiple inboxes etc.

I am using VBA in Excel 2021 to email attachments. During this process I am prompted to select an Outlook account from a list of email addresses that is populated when run. When I select an account the correct data is returned.

When I try to use this data to create an email and place it in the selected user's draft folder it defaults to going into the Primary (First Defined) Accounts Draft folder.

```vb
With outlookMail
    .SendUsingAccount = "Administrator@xyz.com.au"
    '.SendUsingAccount = olAccount ' Set the sending account
    .To = emailAddress.Value
    .Subject = "Your Worksheet: " & ws.Name
    .Body = "Dear " & consultantName.Value & "," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _ 
       "Please find attached the calculation of your latest commission payment." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "This  payment was processed in this month’s payroll." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "Should you have any queries regarding the attached, please do not hesitate to contact your line manager." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "Kind regards," & vbCrLf & _
        "Shann"
    .Attachments.Add fileName ' Attach the PDF file
    .Close olSave
```

I resorted to hardcoding the address as above whilst trying to work out what is going on and this still does not work.

I came across this [Microsoft Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-create-a-sendable-item-for-a-specific-account-based-on-the-current-folder) that seems to highlight the issue. No VBA code is provided to address it.

I tried to use both the `SendUsingAccount` property as well as the `SendOnBehalfOfUser` property and both have the same result.

I regularly manually send emails from each of the defined accounts in my profile.

Answer (score 0):

Aah - the Internet - found the answer here whilst killing time

Use this code block with the Set property rather than the assignment as previously

Set .SendUsingAccount = oAccount

So the code block looks like this now

```
' Compose the email
                    With outlookMail
                         Set .SendUsingAccount = olAccount
                        .To = emailAddress.Value
                        .Subject = "Your Worksheet: " & ws.Name
                        .Body = "Dear " & consultantName.Value & "," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                                "Please find attached the calculation of your latest commission payment." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                                "This  payment was processed in this month’s payroll." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                                "Should you have any queries regarding the attached, please do not hesitate to contact your line manager." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                                "Kind regards," & vbCrLf & _
                                "Shann"
                        .Attachments.Add fileName ' Attach the PDF file
                        .Close olSave
                        '.Send ' Send the email
                    End With '
```